# How to check the existence of a value in an ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala, arraybuffer

I am new in Scala and I am writing a program in which I have an ArrayBuffer of points of a binary image and I want to check in a loop if a specific point is existing in that ArrayBuffer do not add. This is the part of code I am working on :

```
var vectVisitedPoint= new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Point]()
    var pTemp=new Point (0,0)
    var res = new Array[Byte](1)
    img.get(pTemp.x.toInt,pTemp.y.toInt,res) //img is a binary image
    var value1: Int=0
    var value2: Int=0
    scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable {
            while((value1 < img.rows ) ){
                    while ( (value2 < img.cols )){
                             if (res(0) == -1 && vectVisitedPoint.exists(value1,value2)) {//this is where I want to check if the current point (value1,value2) is already exists in vectVisitedPoint
                                    pTemp.x=(pTemp.x.toInt)+value1
                                    pTemp.y=(pTemp.y.toInt)+value2
                                    vectVisitedPoint.append(new Point(pTemp.x,pTemp.y)
                                    scala.util.control.Breaks.break()
                              }
                    value2=value2+1
                    img.get(value1,value2,res)
                    }
            value2=0
            value1=value1+1
            }
    }
}
```

I think I need to write it in another way but don't know how?!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you translating the code from a Java interface? Is img.get your own method or coming from an API? Also, are you sure that the logic in your program is correct? If you break out of the cycle, you start it with img.get calculated for some point in the previous row. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Ashalynd I am not translating it and yes the algorithm works if I wanna find one line in my image but I wanted to find all lines compare them and get the longest [this is my original code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654068/finding-the-longest-branch-in-a-binary-image) it is a skeleton image with lot of lines. so the one in here is used to ind the start point of line and I want to put the all points from that line in an arraybuffer to point it as visited and next time that I want to find another start point of line I check if it has been visited or not. this is what the program does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
vectVisitedPoint.exists(_ == (value1, value2))
```

Would you like me to refactor your code for you into much much less code, more functional, more readible and probably more efficient way? If so create another question and I will.

Comment: [here is my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712299/how-to-change-the-following-code-into-more-functional-more-readable-and-more-ef)