# How to change the following code into more functional, more readable and more efficient one?

Tags: scala

I'm working on a code to find the longest branch and here is a function to find the next unvisited point in my binary image:
Note: I am saving the arraybuffer of found pixels in vectVisitedPoint.

```
var vectVisitedPoint= new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Point]()
    var pTemp=new Point (0,0)
    var res = new Array[Byte](1)
    img.get(pTemp.x.toInt,pTemp.y.toInt,res) //img is a binary image
    var value1: Int=0
    var value2: Int=0
    scala.util.control.Breaks.breakable {
            while((value1 < img.rows ) ){
                    while ( (value2 < img.cols )){
                             if (res(0) == -1 && vectVisitedPoint.exists(_ == (value1, value2))) {
                                    pTemp.x=(pTemp.x.toInt)+value1
                                    pTemp.y=(pTemp.y.toInt)+value2
                                    vectVisitedPoint.append(new Point(pTemp.x,pTemp.y)
                                    scala.util.control.Breaks.break()
                              }
                    value2=value2+1
                    img.get(value1,value2,res)
                    }
            value2=0
            value1=value1+1
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and  doesn't fit well stackoverflow site. Probably you'll get more feedback at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nice! Thanks I didn't know about codereview, the reason I've put my question here is that @samthebest in my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705715/how-to-check-the-existence-of-a-value-in-an-arraybuffer) offered to help me about this!

Comment: No problem, that kind of questions are often ignored here, so I just pointed to the appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4e6 is probably correct in his comment (sorry, my fault), there is maybe too much code here to be an SO question, usually questions of the form "what is the Scala equivalent of ..." are accepted but perhaps some feel this question isn't really of that form.  Nevertheless I'll answer it here and the mods can move it if they like

```
def longestBranch(binImage: TypeOfBinImage): Vector[Point] = {
  var res = new Array[Byte](1)

  def getRes(x: Int, y: Int) = {
    binImage.get(x, y, res)
    res
  }

  (0 until img.rows).foldLeft(Vector.empty[Point])((visited, x) => 
    (0 until img.cols).find(y => 
      getRes(x, y)(0) == -1 && visited.exists(_ == (x, y)))
    .map(y => visited :+ new Point(visited.last + x, visited.last + y))
    .getOrElse(visited)
  )
}
```

Note: I don't think this is more/less efficient, but it certainly is more Scalaery

Comment: Well the code is much clearer but it **is** less efficient whenever `img.rows` becomes huge, since `0 until img.cols` will create a new object for each iteration on the rows. Take a look at this http://ochafik.com/blog/?p=806. If efficiency is a major concern, I would not recommend this implementation. Otherwise, it is fine and more readable.